# Авторизация для гостей в laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Для авторизации я использую [политики](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/authorization#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) laravel. Проблема в том, что они не работают для гостей. Как мне проверить права для гостей?

Мой код:

В контроллере:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize($post);
        return $post->all();
    }
}
```

В политике:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    // Эта функция выполняется только для аутентифицированных пользователей. 
    // Хотелось бы, чтобы она выполнялась и для гостей
    public function index(User $user)
    {            
        return $user->can('get-posts');
    }
}
```

Мне нужна возможность ограничения доступа к методам контроллера для некоторых пользователей. Права будут храниться в БД и их можно будет менять через админку. Мне кажется, что для этого подходит стандартный механизм политик, там я мог проверять доступ к каждому методу контроллера + с помощью модуля [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) в базе хранятся роли и привилегии для пользователей. И при любом запросе я могу проверить права с помощью метода $user->can(). Но всё то не работает для гостей. Я не понимаю, почему так сделано, ведь у пользователей тоже есть права. И непонятно, как теперь проверять, есть ли у пользователей привилегии на какое-либо действие

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит конечно от того насколько ваше приложение будет большим. Но могу обратить ваше внимание на [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#global-middleware) такого рода проверки обычно хватает для малых приложений. Если вам нужно привязывать конкретно к каждому пользователю права и его роль в системе можете реализовать это сами обвернув существующий `User` но если вы не хотите изобретать велосипед то вам [сюда](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission), это не единственный пакет и их много ключевое слово `laravel access rights user` :)